# Designing password text with show password button

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, imageview

I am trying to design `EditText` for password with show password imageView. However I cannot design it correctly beacuse I cannot see `ImageView`, since `EditText's layout_width="fill_parent"`. When I change it to `wrap_content`, I can see my `ImageView` but then it looks very bad in UI. Is it possible to design it without giving fixed size?

Here is my code;

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/registerPassword"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/register_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_login_password_visibility"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_partial_secure"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:clickable="true"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

android:layout_weight=1 solved issue. Now I can see ImageView left of EditText. However now, I TextInputLayout hint is not working.

[image: Here Hint works]

[image: Here Hint does not works]

Comment: the latest support library have built-in support for password toggle. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#rev24-2-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set `android:weightSum` of `LinearLayout` to "1". Then, set `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_weight` of `EditText` to "0dp" and "1", respectively.

Comment: please see my edit, after your changes hint does not work for password field

Comment: These changes have nothing to do with the `EditText` hint.

Comment: Aha then it is because of LinearLayout. is it possible to use another option rather than linearlayout horizantal orientation?

Comment: Yeah, you can use `RelativeLayout`, and align `ImageView` to the right of `EditText`. Google it for example usage.

Comment: Try using `TextInputEditText` instead of `EditText`. See here for example usage: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html

Answer (score 4):

You don't need use ImageView.

Support Library adds support for the password visibility toggle in [recent update](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#24-2-0-api-updates) (revision 24.2.0 - August 2016).

try it:

> setPasswordVisibilityToggleDrawable(int resId)
>
> Set the icon to use for the password visibility toggle button.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use weight?

`android:layout_weight="1"`

and

`android:layout_width="0dp"` or `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/registerPassword"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/register_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_login_password_visibility"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_partial_secure"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: layout_weight solved the problem however now I lost TextInputLayout properties...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:paddingRight="60dp"
                />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/showpass"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-60dp"
                style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/pass_ic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a TextInputLayout with passwordToggleDrawable .

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputPasswordLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:passwordToggleContentDescription="Show" 
            app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/ic_password_visibility_selector"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:hint="@string/enter_your_password"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

`app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/ic_password_visibility_selector"` **assign your drawable**